# Using TailChainMoveSelector

Tags: optaplanner

I'm using the `6.2.0.CR4` release of `OptaPlanner` and according to [its release notes](http://www.optaplanner.org/download/releaseNotes/releaseNotes6.2.html#NewAndNoteWorthy) the best performing configuration for VRP-type problems is a union of `changeMove`, `swapMove`, and `tailChainSwapMove`. I've been unable to get `OptaPlanner` to recognise my simple configuration of just `changeMove` and `tailChainSwapMove`.

```
<localSearch>
   <unionMoveSelector>
       <changeMoveSelector />
       <tailChainSwapMoveSelector />
   </unionMoveSelector>
   <acceptor>
        <lateAcceptanceSize>2000</lateAcceptanceSize>
    </acceptor>
    <forager>
        <acceptedCountLimit>1</acceptedCountLimit>
    </forager>
    <termination>
        <unimprovedStepCountLimit>500000</unimprovedStepCountLimit>
    </termination>
</localSearch>
```

The error reported is that

```
No such field org.optaplanner.core.config.heuristic.selector.move.composite.UnionMoveSelectorConfig.tailChainSwapMoveSelector
```

It seems like the `unionMoveSelector` is not setup to handle `tailChainSwapMoveSelector`s. Am I encountering a problem with my configuration, or are the relevant features not supported in the `6.2.0.CR4` release yet?

Comment: tailChainSwapMoveSelector is not yet in CR4, it is basically new in 6.2.0.Final (not really, we had a less efficient prototype called twoOptMoveSelector which it replaces). 6.2.0.Final should go out any day now (TM) - just waiting on one of the other KIE projects.

Comment: Okay, thanks @GeoffreyDeSmet I was hoping to use the tailChainSwapMove mainly because of the NearbySelector support. Do you have any advice about / examples of how I could combine a custom `MoveIteratorFactory` with the NearbySelectors?

Comment: MoveIteratorFactory gives you total freedom... and no out-of-the-box features such as nearby selection - re-implementing it there is probably overkill and will take lots of time. Just use 6.2.0-SNAPSHOT and use tailChainSwapMove's.

Comment: The 6.2.0-SNAPSHOT distribution from https://hudson.jboss.org/hudson/job/optaplanner/ doesn't work either, it's bundle version is 6.2.0.20140808-1238. Am I looking in the wrong place?

Comment: The build 4299, located at https://hudson.jboss.org/hudson/job/optaplanner/4299/ and tagged as 6.3.0-SNAPSHOT does work though.